# Why does changing backgroundColor change the shape of a button?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In a new project created with create-react-app I have this code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button style={{backgroundColor: "initial"}}>mybutton1</button>
      <button >mybutton2</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Which in Firefox renders the image shown.

[image: buttons]

Why does changing `backgroundColor` change the shape of my button?

Edit: Here is how it is rendered in Chromium:

[image]

Edit 2: Opening the following file in Firefox with a clean profile gives the same result as in image 1. So it's a Firefox problem, not a React problem.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button style="background-color:initial">mybutton</button>
        <button>mybutton2</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the result in chrome?

Comment: Which browser are you using? I can't replicate it in edge (chromium) on windows.

Comment: It looks as if it's not changing the shape, but rather the border type. For button one, it is having an outset border, whereas button two just has the default. Perhaps check any other code, since that is most likely what is causing this.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 82.0.2 on linux.

Comment: @MutedOriginal: You are right, I can get the buttons to look the same by setting border-style to outset. But going through all values for border-style listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) I can not find a way to set both to same style as `mybutton2` in first image.

Comment: Besides just changing the CSS for both buttons, I'd recommend inspecting button2 (right click > Inspect Element), and grabbing the styles directly from there, and then popping it into the CSS or style="" for button1. Although it doesn't directly answer the question asked, I'd consider it a valid solution

Comment: @MutedOriginal please tell me if my answer below is not clear, I'll try to paraphrase it. But in short when you don't specify background or border styles Firefox applies some default theme and so it looks like with different shape. For the first button background: initial is specified so it's rendered according to the spec with transparent background without applying additional styles.This is just how it works, you can look into its source code

Comment: @Andy, I was stating a potential solution to the problem, regardless of existing solutions. If they want the buttons to look the same, I recommended applying the default styling to each instead of relying on the way Firefox rendered it, which you (correctly) explained.

Comment: @MutedOriginal I just provided the explanation because the question begins with "Why". But you provided the solution and I completely agree with it.

Comment: @MutedOriginal: I tried inspecting button2 with inspect element, but there are no css properties there.

Comment: Huh, must be with Firefox like that. I know in Chrome you can inspect the element, and then look at the bottom half of the pane that appears, and it has a styles section there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec the *Initial* value of the *background-color* is **transparent**

So the first button is rendered with transparent background

Also internally Gecko uses some rules when to apply default theme, see this line https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/a147181ece866c1ecd176ac49f112785f960aac0/widget/nsNativeTheme.cpp#L268

And that explains why when you change background or border style it doesn't apply the default theme

Comment: You explain it better in your comment above where you say: "But in short when you don't specify background or border styles Firefox applies some default theme and so it looks like with different shape".

Comment: So the solution is to apply some style to all buttons, that way they are all consistent. But I still don't know any way to get the default style with different colors.